# Image fit to frames (Woocommerce)

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, image-size

I have a problem fitting images while keeping the aspect ratio in the online catalog. I use CSS, and now it looks much better, but some of the images of products doesn't fit the frame. How to make always images fit without cut in a whole in frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Voreny said, it is because the images that are being used are cropped. But in case if you want to contain the image without cropping use `object-fit:contain`.

If you want to make the image `100% or cover` but maintaining the image proportion use `object-fit:cover`. But this property will crop your image a bit to maintain the proportion.

Try this:

```
.woocommerce-page .product-holder .product-img{
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
display: flex; // Remove this
}
.woocommerce-page .product-holder .product-img.no-border img{
    height: 185px;
    object-fit:contain;
}
```

Comment: You are right. Images was cropped. Now I set off "crop" in woocommerce and regenerate thumbanails. It's better but width of frames decreasedto images.
What I should do to every image be all within the frame, the frames be the same and images be center in frames?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question..Can you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Ok. As you can see now images are fitted to frame, but frames has different width. I would like to make:
- all gray frames the same size (width, height)
- image fit to frame with proportion
- image in the middle of the frame

Comment: You are master! It works :) Thank you very much. There is only a problem with hover. When I move on the image there is animation it zoom in (so big) and out. Before there is only litte zoom out. How to come back to previous transition?

Comment: What you can do is change the image scaling on hover.. something thing this.. `transform: scale(1.1)` or some value to control the zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source it's those images that are cropped this way, not styling's fault.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11069827)

Comment: @maskacovnik I would say this IS the answer. Because the images are cropped already they don't fit. It's also possible that I don't see the problem here if it's not what I just said.

Comment: You are right, I was inattentive while reviewing, +1 for right answer